# Story with Wolverine? in wheelchair + Beast being cared for by younger mutant on journey

Tags: story-identification, marvel, comics, x-men, wolverine

I'm trying to find a story I read a year or so ago. This is what I recall: Wolverine is basically an invalid and confined to a wheelchair, Beast has been damaged and has the mental capacity of a small child. They are being cared for by a younger mutant. They are traveling to a meet-up point with other mutants. (I know this rings of the *Logan* movie a bit, but that is not it).

I think it was back-up story in an annual or another series. I say that simply because I don't recall it being very long. Due to all the retcon and reincarnation stuff, I have no idea where to start looking. I want to say that I was reading *Old Man Logan* or other of the 'Logan is old and dying' series when I encountered this... but that doesn't seem to make sense to have a backup story where he is actually killed.

Spoiler alert for anyone that is enticed by the lead in.

> In the end, the group successfully reaches the destination to find that the location was a trap. Due to their slow travel, they have arrived too late only to see the aftermath. Their loved ones are dead and the area is scorched earth. Nothing left but death and destruction. At this point hope is lost. The young mutant kills? Beast somehow and sets fire to Wolverine as that is the only way to end his life. The end.

If this rings a bell to anyone, I'd appreciate a hint as to where to find it so I can re-read it. Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is ***[Astonishing X-Men: Ghost Boxes #2](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Astonishing_X-Men:_Ghost_Boxes_Vol_1_2)***, the concluding issue of a two-part mini-series.

The issue contained two short stories, both set in the alternate reality of [Earth-90227](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Earth-90227). The younger mutant you mentioned was that reality's version of [Hisako Ichiki](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Hisako_Ichiki_(Earth-90227)), AKA Armor. The [Beast](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Henry_McCoy_(Earth-90227)) was said to have the mind of a child, and [Wolverine](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/James_Howlett_(Earth-90227)) was wheelchair-bound.

The story concludes just as you described, with the trio discovering that their journey had been in vain, and  Hisako subsequently beheading the Beast, and burning Wolverine to death. It was implied that she herself starved to death shortly afterward.

> HISAKO: If we don't get there today. We start starving tomorrow. And I'd die first. **Then Henry.** But I wouldn't be around to see **a man with the mind of a child** try to understand why there's no food and he's dying. And then Logan. Though sometimes I wonder if anything short of incineration would kill him.
>
> [image: Panel from Astonishing X-Men: Ghost Boxes #2 as described in the answer text]
>
> HISAKO: Beating Logan unconscious was easy. Logan waking up after I got the fire started under him, not so much. His healing factor died after seven or eight hours in the blaze. The rest of him went soon after.
>
> [image: Panel from Astonishing X-Men: Ghost Boxes #2 as described in the answer text]
>
> <sub>*Astonishing X-Men: Ghost Boxes #2* (January, 2009)</sub>

Comment: Comics are great fun ain’t they.